# Connect OpenWrt router to home wifi AND open wifi

Tags: networking, openwrt

I've noticed I'm within comfortable wifi range of a nearby coffee shop's open connection. I have an OpenWRT router that I'm not using, and thought it might be handy to have this connected to my home network (either via ethernet or wifi - I have a spare USB wifi card too) AND via the open wifi simultaneously. For example I could set it downloading files when my ip has reached filehost IP limits.

How would I go about this? I've messed around a little with /etc/network/interfaces & could probably follow a tutorial for doing this, but it seems it not a use case that's widely discussed. (Or I just lack the vocabulary to google it successfully...)

Comment: You're looking to run it in client mode, aka station mode. Those terms will find you a lot of info with Google. [I also suggest you confirm what you want to do is legal. That depends on your local laws, of course.]

Comment: Great - thanks. It looks like "Routed Client (Using MASQUERADE)" [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/clientmode) is what I was  trying to describe. (Or a superset thereof :)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the new router to connect to the Hotspot in Repeater mode.  Set the routers ip to be in the same subnet as your main router.  Then either 1) add a virtual wireless interface with the same SSID as your wireless network and connect those routers with WDS, or depending on location of the routers 2) connect them via ethernet.  At that point you can just set certain clients to use the gateway of your new router connected to the hotspot.  I've documented my similar setup here:  [Dual Gateway with failover](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=280531).

Comment: I don't know the difference in client and repeater mode on open wrt, but I think in client mode you can't add a virtual interface to bridge via wds.